# Stack Overflow: Please consolidate tags [tortisesvn] (sic!), [tortoisesvn] and [tortoise]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

The tag [tortisesvn](/questions/tagged/tortisesvn) is just a spelling error.
Most questions containting [tortoise](/questions/tagged/tortoise) also have [svn](/questions/tagged/svn), so the more specific [tortoisesvn](/questions/tagged/tortoisesvn) should by used. The other `tortoise*` tags can have the other one or two remaining post.

Comment: I retagged everything tagged [[`tortisesvn`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tortisesvn)]

Comment: I retagged anything tagged `[tortoise]` and not `[svn]` or `[tortoisesvn]` -- a couple were `[tortoisecvs]`, the rest of the `[tortoise]`s overlap, and should be able to be merged to `[tortoisesvn]` safely.

Comment: [tortoise] --> [tortoisesvn] merge complete.

Comment: Ah, is this how we propose that typo tags be deleted? :P